# Why does this query perform better than the ANSI JOIN version?

Tags: oracle, performance

I've been trying to improve the performance of this query for awhile now, and after trying multiple different approaches I found that removing the ANSI JOIN and using conventional syntax reduces the cost according to the explain plan **significantly** (459928 vs. 82518117). Here is the original (snipped and trimmed):

```
select distinct api.locn_id         -- Explain Plan: 82518117
                 ,i.item_set_id
                 ,api.variant_id
    from all_planogram_items api
    join includes i
      on api.variant_id = i.variant_id
      or api.dept_id = i.dept_id
      or api.category_id = i.category_id
      or api.fixture_id = i.fixture_id
      or api.aisle_id = i.aisle_id
   where 1 = 1
     and /* variant is not in excludes list*/
        --e.item_set_id is null
         not exists
... etc
```

and the better performance with the conventional join:

```
select distinct api.locn_id        -- Explain Plan: 459928
                 ,i.item_set_id
                 ,api.variant_id
    from all_planogram_items api, includes i
   where 1 = 1
     and (api.variant_id = i.variant_id
      or api.dept_id = i.dept_id
      or api.category_id = i.category_id
      or api.fixture_id = i.fixture_id
      or api.aisle_id = i.aisle_id)
     and /* variant is not in excludes list*/
        --e.item_set_id is null
         not exists
... etc
```

Like I mentioned, there is more to this query (inline views, etc), but the only change I made was here on the join. I have a feeling it has to do with the `or` clauses but I cannot explain it myself. Why is this so much more efficient?

More information:

- The query does actually run faster (about twice as fast), it's not just the plan cost.
- Both queries return the exact same results
- Additional executions of each query result in the same; ANSI JOIN taking about twice as long as the conventional join.
- We are using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit

Here are the explain plans. I want to re-iterate that the only difference in these explain plans is the join method explained above. Oddly, the lower cost and faster conventional JOIN explain plan is over 3 times as large as the slower ANSI JOIN explain plan (sorry for the screenshots, the explain plans are too large to post text versions here):

Conventional JOIN Explain Plan:

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocgOs.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbdOe.png
3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVyQk.png

ANSI JOIN Explain Plan:

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtjUm.png

Comment: Does the query actually run faster or are you looking solely at the cost number?  Is the query plan actually different?  What are the plans?  What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I've added more information to the question, but I don't know the best way to show what the plans actually are.

Comment: I'd use `dbms_xplan` to get the two plans.

Comment: Also is the result of both the queries the same? It is easy to make mistakes while joining in the non-ANSI standard than the ANSI standard

Comment: The second execution of a query is very often faster then the first one due to caching. Does the runtime difference persist if you run each statement multiple times?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Absolutely, I ensured that additional executions was not the reason for this. I've run each query back and forth with the same results.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add **both** execution plans. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, the explain plans are too large to add text versions to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is this so much more efficient?

One of your plans is probably doing OR expansion and the other probably is not.

Oracle's logic to transform ANSI join syntax queries is not perfect and not identical to the logic to transform non ANSI join syntax queries.  If you will look on Oracle's support website for patches, you will see that just about every release has a number of bugfixes in this area.

The answer extended to other areas as well.  For example, in some Oracle versions, you can have a fast-running `SELECT` statement that will tank if you put it into an `INSERT` statement or a `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` statement.

Oracle joins and ANSI joins are conceptually the same and *should* make no difference.  But, in reality, there are differences.

Comment: That all said... I still much prefer the ANSI join syntax and use it almost exclusively.

Comment: This is along the lines of the answer I was expecting/hoping for. I know Oracle has had issues with ANSI JOIN, and I know my specific example is complicated, but if this is what it comes down to then that is all I need to know.

Comment: Thanks.  The `CONCATENATION` step (plus the length) of the first plan you posted seems to confirm my thought that the conventional join query is using OR expansion.  It's hard to tell because I didn't see table names or index names anywhere in the plans.

Comment: Sorry about that, I did intentionally exclude object names with the fear that I was sharing just a little too much information.

Comment: This actually makes me feel uneasy about all the ANSI joins I have been using in our code.

Comment: I wouldn't feel that way.  Any differences are almost by definition "bugs" on Oracle's part.  And one might encounter bugs in any software in any place.  Plus, this is an edge-case: a JOIN condition with ORs, plus other complicating filters.  On any query of this complexity, I'd hope you are testing to make sure that Oracle is giving you what you expect.  Finally, Oracle does find and fix these things.  In this case, I'd guess that the patch for BUG #16516883 (Oracle's support website) has a decent chance of fixing the difference.

Comment: I would also like to note something just found out; our company is in the middle of an Oracle upgrade to 12c from 11g. I've verified that this problem does not exist in 12c, so on my end the solution is to wait until our DBA's apply the upgrade to production.

Answer (score 0):

Explain Plan Cost is generally not a good measure of performance. It can vary for similar queries and not have an affect on performance. You might want to have a look at autotrace statistics and tkprof for more insight. Also see [this link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:40112614814595)

Answer (score 0):

You can see the explain plan for each query easily if you use SQL Developer or Toad (they have a button that shows you the execution plan directly). It would be good to compare the plans, to see if, for example, the Optimizer doesn't "see" the opportunity to push predicates from the join to the component tables or views due to the complex ON condition. Moving the conditions to a WHERE clause allows the Optimizer to look at filters in a different order (perhaps) and to see such opportunities. THIS MAY BE ENTIRELY WRONG but it shows the kind of things you may be able to notice by looking at the explain plans.